# how to create cascading dropdown lists in react

Tags: reactjs, select

Can someone show me how to create three cascading dropdown lists, if it is possible using the office-ui-fabric-react?

Another question, when the value is changed in the first dropdown, how do you reset the index in the second list to show the first item as selected?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you just have to change the `options` other dropdowns depending on the value you get at `onChanged`.
For selecting the first item as selected, just set the `selectedKey` to the first item when the first dropdown calls `onChanged`.

Comment: can I use the same "onchanged" event handler on three components and how can I detect which component fired the event? As at the moment all three of them are firing at the same time. I am using the same component for three different data options.

Comment: `onChanged` can be on each component. For simplicity, you can have 3 different methods attached to each to assure they're different. I'm not sure how all 3 are firing at the same time without looking at your code.

Comment: thanks for your reply. When I use one event handler for all three events then they fire at the same time. I have to check actually when I use three separate ones.

I thought there will be a way like like in .net.

Answer (score 0):

As presented in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087439/5506730), this is a possible way how I would implement the dynamic selection of a dropdown component. You can use the `DropDown` component recursively by passing the component itself as a child of another dropdown;

```js
const SomeComponent = () => 'SomeComponent';
const Foo = () => 'Foo';
const Bar = () => 'Bar';

class ListItem extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const { option: {id}, onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(id);
  }
  
  render(){
    const { option: { label } } = this.props;
    return (
      <li onClick={this.handleClick}>{label}</li>
    )
  }
}

class DropDown extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null
  }
  
  handleOptionClick = optionId => {
    const { options } = this.props;
    this.setState({ selectedOption: options.find(option => option.id === optionId).child });
  }
  
  render(){
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    const { options } = this.props;
    return (
      <ul>
        {options.map(option => (
          <ListItem
            option={option}
            onClick={this.handleOptionClick}
          />
        ))}
        {selectedOption}
       </ul>
     )
  }
}

const DropDownOptions = [
  {id: '1', label: 'label-1', child: <SomeComponent />},
  {id: '2', label: 'label-2', child: <DropDown options={[
    {id: '2-1', label: 'label-2-1', child: <Foo />},
    {id: '2-2', label: 'label-2-2', child: <Bar />}
  ]} />}
]

ReactDOM.render(<DropDown options={DropDownOptions} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```