# How to dynamically generate dropdown from nested array in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I can make nested dropdown without problems but I have no idea how to make it dynamic. It can go even up to 5-8 levels deep. I understand that it could be done with help of .map() function which will be called inside itself again if there is any more sub-dropdowns. So this way I could access all data but what to do next I don't know.

Array looks something like this(Just some part of it):

```
categories = [
  {
    title : "Electronics", path : "Electronics", id : 1, subCat: [
      {title : "Computers", path : "Electronics->Computers", id : 11, subCat: [
        {title : "Desktop", path : "Electronics->Computers->Desktop", id : 111, subCat: [
          {title : "Gaming", path : "Electronics->Computers->Desktop->Gaming", id : 1111, subCat: null},
          {title : "Office", path : "Electronics->Computers->Desktop->Office", id : 1112, subCat: null}
        ]},
        {title : "Laptops", path : "Electronics->Computers->Laptops", id : 112, subCat: [
          {title : "Gaming", path : "Electronics->Computers->Laptops->Gaming", id : 1121, subCat: null},
          {title : "Office", path : "Electronics->Computers->Laptops->Office", id : 1122, subCat: null}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]
  },
  {
    title : "Cars", path : "Cars", id : 2, subCat: [
      {title : "Parts & Accessories", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories", id : 21, subCat: [
        {title : "Car Parts", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Car Parts", id : 211, subCat: null},
        {title : "Car Accessories", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Car Accessories", id : 211, subCat: null},
        {title : "Parts", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Parts", id : 212, subCat: null},
        {title : "Paintwork", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Paintwork", id : 213, subCat: null},
        {title : "Tyres & Rims", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Tyres & Rims", id : 214, subCat: [
          {title : "Tyres", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Tyres & Rims->Tyres", id : 2141, subCat: null},
          {title : "Rims", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Tyres & Rims->Rims", id : 2142, subCat: null},
          {title : "Trims", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Tyres & Rims->Trims", id : 2143, subCat: null},
          {title : "Accessories", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Tyres & Rims->Accessories", id : 2144, subCat: [
            {title : "Hub Centre Caps", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Tyres & Rims->Accessories->Hub Centre Caps", id : 21441, subCat: null},
            {title : "Valve Caps", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Tyres & Rims->Accessories->Valve Caps", id : 21442, subCat: null},
            {title : "Tyre Bags", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Tyres & Rims->Accessories->Tyre Bags", id : 21443, subCat: null}
            {title : "Bolts & Nut Covers", path : "Cars->Parts & Accessories->Tyres & Rims->Accessories->Bolts & Nut Covers", id : 21444, subCat: null}
          ]},
        ]}
      ]}
    ]
  }
]
```

Could anybody help me out here please with some idea or example? Thanks.

Comment: Share the piece of code you have so far

Comment: Can you please give the data you are using to nest?

Comment: Can you add sourcecode?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow SlimEddy! This is not a code writing service. It sounds like you have a good idea of an approach. Try that and come back with specific questions if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Please, check my answer here, it might cover your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004421/how-to-create-cascading-dropdown-lists-in-react. This way you can create unlimited cascading dropdowns.

Comment: So far I don't have nothing for dynamic dropdown. In my file I just have map() function because no idea what to do next. But I added how my array look like.

Comment: @gazdagergo If I understand correct then to have sub-dropdown I must use <DropDown options={[ ]} /> every time right ? So that means I must generate new array from existing so it have <DropDown /> right ?

Comment: Yes, you should generate this array within the JSX code so you are able to add a JSX element (<DropDown />) into it. If you get the original array dynamically from the server as a prop I recommend to use e.g. `getDerivedStateFromProps` to remap it and store it in the state. This is one of the main cons of JSX that you can add even components into an array or object as value. So why not to use it.

Comment: @gazdagergo Played a bit around using static data and all works nice. But is there a way to display {selectedOption} under selected option ?

Comment: If you'd like to display the selected option of a deeper nested dropdown item in the parent I recommend to add an `onSelect` prop to `DropDown` and pass a handler function from the top parent component. Inside `DropDown` implement some handler which calls this onSelect with the selected value. E.g. triggered by click or triggered by the changed `selectedOption` state.

Comment: @SlimEddy, did you find any of the answers useful?

Comment: @gazdagergo Your comment is more helpful then current answer. But In your comment there must be done few thinks before it can be succeed, like recreate array from server and that step should not be there. So im trying to use your example coz i dont have others anyway and make it work in my way. And trying to add proper way to display child elements under correct parent. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna make something that can be dynamically nested, you can make a component that can render itself and then pass down the current level of items to render.

If you look at this simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rln82loyj4?fontsize=14

It renders one component initially and gives it an array of strings and arrays. In the component, it maps through each item and checks if it is an array or not. If it's an array, it will create another element but increment the level and provide next group of items to map through. The level is currently used to set a margin left to make it look tiered.

It's a pretty simple example but the concept should be applicable to what you want - the best way to solve your problem will to make something recursive.